# Requirements for developing with ArcGIS for Android?

Tags: arcgis-android

I want to develop a GIS application based on the ArcGIS for Android SDK.

What are the hardware and software needed by a client to run this project after building it?

Comment: (-1) The question is useful but please do exert some effort next time. The answer to your question can be found with a simple Google search with the keywords in your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Build your application with the ArcGIS Android SDK** - http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-android/sdk

> Requires Android version 2.2 (Froyo) and above. The ArcGIS app will
>   only run on an Android emulator running the 4.0.3 system image with
>   hardware accelaratin enabled.
>
> The ArcGIS for Android application has been designed for Android
>   devices equipped with ARMv6 and ARMv7 processors. However, some
>   exceptions exist and therfore some ARMv6 devices will not be supported
>   and will not be able to find the application in the Android Market.
>   The current list of unsupported devices is the  HTC Mytouch 3G

Help  Guide

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/android-sdk/concepts/index.html#/System_requirements/011900000004000000/

API Reference Guide

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/android-sdk/api/index.html